# Python.exe appcrash with Ghost.py

Tags: python, crash, ghost.py

I'm using Ghost.py

```
    from ghost import Ghost
    url = "http://www.kiev.prom.ua"
    gh = Ghost()
    page, page_name = gh.create_page()
    page_resource = page.open(url, wait_onload_event=True)
```

When I run the above script, Python crashes:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH 
   Application Name: python.exe 
   Application Version: 0.0.0.0 
   Application Timestamp: 4c303241 
   Name of the module with the error: python27.dll 
   Version of the module with the error: 2.7.5150.1013 
   The time stamp module with the error: 5237f3d5 
   Exception Code: c0000005 
   Exception Offset: 00107f7a 
   OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1 
   Language Code: 1049 
   Additional Information 1: 0a9e 
   Additional information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789 
   Additional Information 3: 0a9e 
   Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

How can I find the source of this problem?

Comment: I was wondering if you have found the cause of the crash? I bumped into these mysterious crashes recently.

Comment: @sqd , sorry, but i I have not found a solution of this problem still . I use selenium instead now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you get crashes like this instead of regular [Python exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html), the problem is somewhere in the C code, and usually in a third party library.

You have provided a minimal program that produces your error, which is great. I've never used Ghost myself, so this answer is just my best guesses since you haven't gotten any other answers yet.

**Try to make your program even more minimal**. Does the following program also crash?

```
from ghost import Ghost
gh = Ghost()
```

If not, are you using one of the methods the wrong way? Read [the Ghost documentation](http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py) carefully and **make sure that you're using the library in the correct way**. For example, I found the method `create_page`, but only in an online [documentation that seems a bit outdated](http://carrerasrodrigo.github.io/Ghost.py/). There is some documentation [here as well](http://ghostpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

**Get the latest version of the library and use the included documentation, or generate it yourself.**

Finally, the documentation also says the following about PyQt/PySide:

> First you need to install PyQt or PySide. This will require to install
>   the QT framework first. You can find PyQt in the following link
>   http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download

So **the problem might also be with your PyQt/PySide installation**, but that's not a question for StackOverflow I think.